# Use Expo SecureStore to save login credentials to Keychain

Tags: react-native, expo

What is the best way to use [Expos SecureStore](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/securestore.html) to save login credentials (say Email + Password) so that the iOS Keychain (and Android's Keystore system at the same time if possible) can associate it with the App that stores the credentials?

Of interest here is the third param of `SecureStore.setItemAsync(…, …, options)`. It would be optimal if the `options` map was set to save the credentials in a way that iOS will (automatically) allow the User to retrieve them from the Keychain when the App is started and the User needs to log in in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using SecureStore automatically associates the keychain with the saving app. As long as you use the same key (the first parameter) your app should be able to retrieve the value (the second parameter).

There is no option exposed to automatically retrieve the app when the app is started, but you can achieve the same effect by retrieving the keys using `getItemAsync` when you load the root view of your app.

The options parameter controls if you need extra security around when the app can retrieve the value using the key (for instance if it can access the keys while the device is locked, or after the app is moved to a new device)

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/securestore